# React-Navigation: Navigate screen when Declared

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import MainNavigator from "./src/navigation";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class Application extends Component<Props> {
  _checkToken(token) {
    //TODO: Validate token!
    return true;
  }

  _isLoggedin() {
    if (this._checkToken(this.props.token)) {
      MainNavigator.navigate("Home");
    } else {
      MainNavigator.navigate("Login");
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this._isLoggedin();
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this._isLoggedin();
  }

  render() {
    return MainNavigator;
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { token: state.auth.token };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Application);
```

Navigator:

```
MainNavigator = SwitchNavigator({
  intro: { screen: introScreen },
  login: { screen: loginScreen },
  Home: { screen: homeScreen }
});
```

I would like this component (Application) to be responsible for navigating the view to the correct screen depending on the authentication state that is retrieved from redux/redux-persist. I implemented this approach because I would like the user to be able to close the App without the need to log in again. Hence, when  `componentDidUpdate`  or  `componentDidMount`  is triggered I check the validity of the stored token and try to navigate based on that.

My issue is how do I navigate through  `MainNavigator` 's Screens? The documentation addressed navigation by using  `this.props.navigation.navigate([ScreenName])`  but I can't use this method here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a NavigationService as described in the [official documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html)

Just create a new NavigationService.js file.

```
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

let _navigatorRef;

function setNavigatorRef(navigatorRef) {
  _navigatorRef = navigatorRef;
}

function navigate(routeName, params) {
  _navigatorRef.dispatch(
    NavigationActions.navigate({
      routeName,
      params,
    })
  );
}

export default {
  navigate,
  setNavigatorRef,
};
```

In your top level component you can pass the Navigator to your service like this.

```
import NavigationService from './NavigationService';

const MyNavigator = createStackNavigator({ bla bla bla })

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MyNavigator
        ref={navigatorRef => {
          NavigationService.setNavigatorRef(navigatorRef);
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Now you can use this service to navigate from your top level component (e.g App.js). Just use the function navigate().

```
NavigationService.navigate('LastScreen');
```

Comment: Thank you so much!